# peek multiple chars from cin with putback

Tags: c++, istream, peek

I need to try to peek multiple characters from a `std::istream` (which could be `std::cin`), so I wrote a simple loop to call `get()` lots of times and then `putback()` lots of times:

```
std::vector<char> peek_many(std::istream& is, int N) {
    std::vector<char> data;
    data.reserve(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        data.push_back(is.get());
    }   

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        is.putback(data[N-i-1]);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Is this guaranteed to work on all `istream`s (whether I'm reading a file, `cin`, `istringstream`, etc)? If not, why not?

Comment: `std::istringstream` is input-only, it can only be read from, you can't `putback()` data into it.

Comment: Off topic, wouldn't it be better to return a shorter vector if `EOF` was reached, instead of returning a vector with trailing `EOF`s?

Comment: @Remy Citation needed

Comment: @AlanStokes: Run the example code at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback.  The `putback()` fails on an `std::istringstream`, and is commented as such.

Comment: @RemyLebeau You can't *modify* it - but you can put the same characters back - which is what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is only safe to assume 1 character "wide" put back buffer. You will have to add additional layer of abstraction to provide more put back space.

Alternatively, if your stream is seekable, you can remember the position before you start tentatively parsing and then seek back to the remembered position.

Comment: What would such an abstraction look like?

Comment: An extra level of buffering in your code. You read data from the stream into your own buffer of sufficient size, and then you can read/peek data from the buffer as needed without trying to put the data back into the stream.

Comment: Or you could call `[pub]setbuf` to tell the `streambuf` that you want a bigger buffer - except that sadly in general that has no useful well-defined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

`putback` calls `sputback` which only works if a putback position is available. Nothing guarantees that there is an indefinite number of such positions.

Comment: When `sputback` returns `EOF` you ran out ;-) Or you can look at `gptr()` vs `eback()`, which gives you a lower bound.

Comment: Those are `protected`.

Comment: Fair point. Assuming you're not willing/able to derive from the `streambuf` I think you're stuck with the first half of my suggestion.